# Can we pass a model to updateOrCreate method of eloquent Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there anyway to pass a model to updateOrCreate method of Eloquent laravel?  My current code is working fine, in which i am passing array to updateOrCreate method.

```
$ud = UserDetail::updateOrCreate(
                     ['user_id' => $user->id],
                     [
                      'father_name' => $request['fname'], 'dob' => $request['dob'], 
                      'contact_no' => $request['contactNumber'], 'img_url' => $url,
                      'postal_address' => $request['postalAddress'],
                      'permanant_address' => $request['permanantAddress'], 
                      'gender' => $request['gender'], 'religion' => $request['religion'], 
                      'marital_status' => $request['maritalStatus'], 
                     'district_id' => $request['district'], 'profile_status' => $status]);
```

I am using updateOrCreate method multiple times. So i want to create a model once, assign these values to the model, then pass it to updateOrCreate method instead of passing a large array.

```
 //Create model and assign values

 $user_d = new UserDetail;
 $user_d->father_name = $request['fname'];
 $user_d->dob = $request['dob'];

 //pass the model to updateOrCreate method
 $ud = UserDetail::updateOrCreate(
                                ['user_id' => $user->id], $user_d );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`attributesToArray`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_attributesToArray) method

```
//Create model and assign values

$user_d = new UserDetail;
$user_d->father_name = $request['fname'];
$user_d->dob = $request['dob'];
$user_d->save();

//pass the model to updateOrCreate method
$ud = UserDetail::updateOrCreate([
          'user_id' => $user->id
      ], $user_d->attributesToArray());
```